# How to create a medal in css

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a medal in css but unfortunately I am stuck creating it how can i create a medal in css/html purely i tried to search over internet but didn't find any perfect result regarding this
please help me to create a medal

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:pseudo` elements

- use skew for the ribbons
- box-shadow for the inner circle

```css
.medal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
}
.ribbon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.ribbon:before {
  right: 0;
  background: #30110E;
  transform: skew(-28deg);
}
.ribbon:after {
  background: #EF7E76;
  transform: skew(28deg);
}
.coin {
  border: 1px solid #CA5D3E;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #F0CD73;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: -15px auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #989898;
}
.coin:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9px #D9B867;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="medal">
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
  <div class="coin"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you start: original on [codepen](http://codepen.io/zohf/pen/oxfrI)

```css
.outer {
  margin: 150px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.outer .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fbc56f;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
.outer .circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #fab84a;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 2;
}
.outer .ribbon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #9bdbf6;
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: -23px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.outer .ribbon:after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 18px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: #9bdbf6;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(70deg);
}
.outer .ribbon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 64px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
</div>
```